# Having issue with calculating sum of an array where user inputs integers

Tags: javascript, arrays

Beginner with javascript, having trouble with the form, the user inputs 5 integers and that goes into an array then the sum is calculated
Getting errors with the event listener with google web dev tools. I'm I way off?

> HTML

```
<article>
<h2> Enter five intergers then click add to calculate the sum </h2>
<h5>please do not include any letters</h5><br>
<br>Enter the 1st number: <input type="text" id="txt1" /><br>
<br>Enter the 2nd number: <input type="text" id="txt2" /><br>
<br>Enter the 3rd number: <input type="text" id="txt3" /><br>
<br>Enter the 4th number: <input type="text" id="txt4" /><br>
<br>Enter the 5th number: <input type="text" id="txt5" /><br>

<br><input type="button" onclick="call()" value="Add" id="sum" />
<br>
</article>
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
function add () {
var txt1  = document.getElementById("txt1");
var txt2  = document.getElementById("txt2");
var txt3  = document.getElementById("txt3");
var txt4  = document.getElementById("txt4");
var txt5  = document.getElementById("txt5");


var arr = [txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4,txt5];
var total=0;
for(var i in arr) { total += arr[i]; }
   if(isNaN(txt1)||isNaN(txt2)||isNaN(txt3)||isNaN(txt4)||isNaN(txt5)){
          alert("please enter a number");
     }
     else

        {

         var result=txt1+txt2+txt3+txt4+txt5;
         alert("The sum is " +result);
       }
       }
      // listener
      function createEventListener() {
         var submitButton = document.getElementById("sum");
         if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
           submitButton.addEventListener("click", add, false); 
         } else if (submitButton.attachEvent)  {
           submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", add);
         }
         document.getElementById('result').result = ""; 
         document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = ""; 
      }

      if (window.addEventListener) {
         window.addEventListener("load", createEventListener, false);
      } else if (window.attachEvent) {
         window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListener);
      }
```

Comment: Where's `call()`?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick is calling call() which you have not defined. I think you meant add()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it should be `add`, not `call`:

```
<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add" id="sum" />
```

Then these have to be changed like this:

```
var txt1 = Number(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
```